# Grails 4.0.3 - problem with `micronaut-http-client` plugin

Tags: grails, httprequest, micronaut, grails-4

I'm trying to upgrade my grails application to Grails 4.0.3. For REST requests I'm trying to use `micronaut-http-client` plugin -> `build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client:2.0.0'
}
```

Unfortunately when I'm running the application with `grails run-app` this stacktrace appears:

```
2020-06-30 15:05:50.260 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanContextException: Error loading bean [io.micronaut.http.client.loadbalance.LoadBalancerConverters]: io/micronaut/inject/annotation/AnnotationMetadataHierarchy
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.lambda$findBeanCandidates$32(DefaultBeanContext.java:1419)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBeanCandidates(DefaultBeanContext.java:1429)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.findBeanCandidates(DefaultApplicationContext.java:241)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.lambda$findBeanCandidatesInternal$68(DefaultBeanContext.java:2473)
    at io.micronaut.core.util.clhm.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.lambda$compute$0(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    at io.micronaut.core.util.clhm.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.compute(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java:733)
    at io.micronaut.core.util.clhm.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java:710)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBeanCandidatesInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2473)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfTypeInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2511)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfType(DefaultBeanContext.java:894)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfType(DefaultBeanContext.java:620)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeTypeConverters(DefaultApplicationContext.java:428)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:235)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:2446)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:200)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:187)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.createApplicationContext(GrailsApp.groovy:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:96)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:456)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:443)
    at example.Application.main(Application.groovy:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/micronaut/inject/annotation/AnnotationMetadataHierarchy
    at io.micronaut.http.client.loadbalance.$LoadBalancerConvertersDefinition.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.loadbalance.$LoadBalancerConvertersDefinitionClass.load(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinitionReference.load(AbstractBeanDefinitionReference.java:63)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.lambda$findBeanCandidates$32(DefaultBeanContext.java:1417)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.micronaut.inject.annotation.AnnotationMetadataHierarchy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 39 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

I did my research but couldn't manage to find the solution.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance~

Comment: Grails 4.0.3 is based on mn 1.x - If you use the matching version it should work. 4.1.x will use mn 2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @erichelgeson. the solution was removing the version completely. This way it installed 1.2.11 version:

```
    compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client'
```